# Run a java program in backend

Tags: java, linux, background, nohup

Hi all i want to run a java application as backend process.that is like tomcat server.For that i had developed one application.and made one class as main class and calling from one script file .i.e(startup.sh) file.in startup.sh file i was calling one class.that is MainMethodClass.In main method class i had written my business logic.when i am running this app in linux server from using putty is is working until putty window is not closed.As closed after putty window it is also stopped.but i need to run this app even i closed also.How can i achieve this.

Comment: possible duplicate of [command execution with nohup in background](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7519539/command-execution-with-nohup-in-background)

Answer (score 45, accepted):

[Nohup](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nohup) will detach a process you run from your current console and let it continue when you close the terminal.  Run something like this.

```
nohup java -jar my.jar &
```

By default it will pipe the output to nohup.out, so if you don't want that you could try:

```
nohup java -jar my.jar > /dev/null &
```

Comment: I want to run following command "java -jar myApp.jar arg1 &", it causes the  nohup: ignoring input and appending output to `nohup.out'. what should I do in order to run the command with input argument?

Answer (score 6):

This problem is not related to java, its actually something related to the way linux operates.

You need to do following:

```
nohup <your_application_command> &
```

Note the "nohup" and "&" at start and end respectively.

Comment: thank you all for your quick responses it is working with sh startup.sh & and i made changes after calling class file i.e MainMethodClass & it is working without interruption.once again thanks to all.

Answer (score 4):

You should be able to do something like:

```
nohup java -jar MyApplication.jar &
```

Answer (score 1):

On a linux machine you can create a service for your jar( executable jar like spring boot )

```
# Set the Application as Service
ln -s $APP_BASE/bin/$APP_NAME.jar /etc/init.d/$APP_NAME

echo "Starting the application as service"
service $APP_NAME start
```